# how to make my expo (react native) android emulator access C# .net backend api using localhost?

Tags: c#, react-native, .net-core, android-emulator

I am trying to build mobile app using react native and expo. When I try to access C# backend for fetching data, I have a "Network request failed" issue. The backend is built using C# .net core 3.0, and there is no authentication applied. For instance, one get request is for fetching all data from database: http://localhost:5000/ref-entity/load-all/0/1

the following are the experiments I have done:

1. the url http://localhost:5000/ref-entity/load-all/0/1 is working in postman.
2. but if I use http://10.0.2.2:5000/ref-entity/load-all/0/1 in expo android emulator, I will get a "Network request failed" error.
3. I have figured out it is the c# backend issue, since if I build a simple backend using node.js, this url http://10.0.2.2:4000/test is absolutely working in the emulator.

I believe it must be the c# backend is blocking the access from android emulator (10.0.2.2), but nodejs is not. I still cannot figure out which configuration I should try.

Comment: I think this might be CORS issue since the request is originating from a different address.  
You can follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1 to configure CORS. While going live you can allow request from any origin and use mechanism like OAUTH or security mechanism of your choice. I hope this helps.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is a local IP address that only works on your internal network. If your phone is using your provider's network it can't reach it because 10.0.2.2 isn't a public IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and its works for me on android EMULATOR whenever I face problems like network request failure.

`http://10.0.2.2:5000`